# IDataObject store managed object reference

Tags: serialization, drag-and-drop, c++-cli, pass-by-reference, pinning

I am trying to implement Drag-and-Drop functionality *within* my C++/CLI application, using the standard WinForms and WPF (managed) APIs.  These APIs accept an object wrapped in an implementation of IDataObject, serialize it, and then deserialize once the drag-and-drop target has been specified.  I do not want the data transferred serialized and deserialized.

A bit more concretely (albeit dramatically simplified):

```
[SerializableAttribute]
ref class MyType : public System::IObserver<Object^>
{
public:
    System::IObservable<Object^> ^myObj;
    static void Watch(MyType ^wrapper)
    {
        myObj->Subscribe(watcher);
    }
private:
    static MyType ^watcher = gcnew MyType();
    void OnCompleted(void) = System::IObserver<Object^>::OnCompleted {}
    void OnError(System::Exception^) = System::IObserver<Object^>::OnError {}
    void OnNext(Object^) = System::IObserver::OnNext
    {
        System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("Hi!");
    }
}
ref class MyControl : public System::Windows::Controls::UserControl
{
public:
    MyControl(void)
    {
        this->Drop += gcnew DragEventHandler(this, &MyControl::this_Drop);
    }
private:
    void this_Drop(Object^, System::Windows::DragEventArgs ^e)
    {
        MyType::Watch(dynamic_cast<MyType^>(e->Data->GetData("MyFormat")));
    }
}
ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myTreeView->ItemDrag += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ItemDragEventHandler(this, &MyForm::myTreeView_ItemDrag);
    }
private:
    MyType ^data = gcnew MyType();
    System::Windows::Forms::TreeView ^myTreeView;
    MyControl ^myControl;
    void modifyMyObjField(MyType^);
    void myEventHandler(Object^, EventArgs^)
    {
        modifyMyObjField(data);
    }
    void myTreeView_ItemDrag(Object^, System::Windows::Forms::ItemDragEventArgs^)
    {
        myTreeView->DoDragDrop(gcnew DataObject("MyFormat", MyType), DragDropEffects::Copy);
    }
}
```

When `myEventHandler` is called, no messagebox appears, because a different `MyType` object receives the IObservable subscription from the one that is modified.

Because all drag-and-drop occurs *cis*-application, I can work around this issue by pinning `MyForm::data` and passing an `IntPtr` back-and-forth.  `MyForm::myTreeView_ItemDrag` becomes

```
{
    myTreeView->DoDragDrop(gcnew DataObject("MyFormat", System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle::Alloc(data, System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandleType::Pinned).ToIntPtr()), DragDropEffects::Copy);
}
```

and `MyControl::this_Drop` becomes

```
{
    System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle handle = System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle::FromIntPtr(*dynamic_cast<IntPtr^>(e->Data->GetData("MyFormat")));
    MyType::Watch(dynamic_cast<MyType^>(handle.Target));
    handle.Free();
}
```

This seems an extraordinarily complicated way to accomplish a simple task, and (obviously) will bog down the garbage collector.  Is there a better way that I am missing?

Comment: Hard to guess why you don't simply pass `data`, no point in passing the MyType.  Event handlers look bad too, you need DragEnter and DragDrop.

Comment: @Hans: I'm just trying to create a minimal working example.  In reality, `MyType` has other members, and, yes, there is another event handler (UIElement::DragOver) to verify that the user is dragging the data to an appropriate location.  **The point is, the serialization breaks my IObservable event subscription, so I need to pass the data unserialized.**